RxJava Scheduler scheduleDirect guarantees
If I have some code like the following:
Schedulers.single().scheduleDirect {
    Schedulers.single().scheduleDirect {
        println("Run inner code") // Line A
    }   
    println("Run outer code") // Line B
}

Is it guaranteed that Line B will always run first, and then Line A will run last, assuming that Schedulers.single() is a single thread backed scheduler (or some other custom scheduler that has a single thread in the thread pool)?

Yes. ~ 11 chars
